# Jquery code redirect html page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to understand that means : "url : 'Show.html'".
Is this a redirect to a html page? 
Because I'm testing with a same code and I haven't a redirect.

I have this code :

```
function showAll(){

$("#contentCamp").empty();
$.ajax({
    url: 'Show.html', 
    dataType: 'html', 
    success: function(data){            
        $("#contentCamp").html(data);
        getAll();
    },
    error: function(e){
        alert("Error loading all html : " + e.statusText);
    }
}); 
}
```

And the others functions

```
function getAll(){

var response;   
var all = []; 

$.ajax({
    type: 'Post', 
    url: url + 'GetAll',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8', 
    dataType: 'json', 
    success: function(msg){
        response = msg.d;
        for(var i=0; i < response.length; i++){
            all[i] = [response[i].name];
        }
        fill(all);
    },
    error: function(e){
        alert("error loading");
    }
})
}

function fill(data) {

if ($("#table").css("visibility") == "hidden")
    $("#table").css("visibility", "visible");

$('#table').dataTable({
    'aaData' : data, 
    'aoColumns' : [{ "sTitle":...}
});
```

};

Comment: No, it's not a redirect call, just the page to get the content from

Comment: No it's not a redirect, it's an Ajax call, that gets the `HTML` from `Show.html`

Comment: SideNote: Why don't you simple use `$("#contentCamp").load('Show.html', function(){getAll();});`

Comment: Because in my friend's code, he has a link that displays the all element, Here is his code:  <li id="all"><a href="#" onclick="showAll();">All</a></li>. And thus, he doesn't redirect a new page, he just replaces the current html page by show.html? Is that correct?